# Hay alguna forma de capturar la salida de mi app compilada a android desde ionic-capacitor?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

Trabajo con Angular, y sé que capacitor tiene plugins que puedes usar, he incluso hay uno que obtiene los estados de la aplicación como "App" de @capacitor/app.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que este plugin captura los estados **de actividad** y no encuentro ningún otro que me sirva.

Están "appRestoredResult","appUrlOpen","backButton" y "appStateChange", siendo este último el que captura si está en primer plano o no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con éste puedo hacer que al enviarse al background se ejecuten mis funciones, pero quiero que sea al eliminar la app, no al enviarla al fondo. Y no encuentro el modo de capturar ese evento.

El evento backbutton podría servirme solo en caso de que el usuario lo cierre de ese modo, pero no si la envía al fondo y después la elimina.

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te recomiendo especificar más tu problema para que te puedan ayudar, ya que por parte se entiende pero no vemos tus avances y/o exactamente el problema que tienes (siempre es buena idea agregar algo de código aunque sea un mock).